# static method called from constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor, static

Question about Java static methods.

```
Animal() 
{ 
    this(makeRandomName());          
}
```

I have this code in Java, that is called when I create an animal object:
`Animal a = new Animal()`
`makeRandomName` is a method that returns a String obtained randomly from an Array of String values, by using `Math.random()`.
If I don't specify the method makeRandomName as **static**, I get this error (can you explain why):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - cannot reference this before supertype constructor has
>   been called

Also, when the Animal constructor is defined like this:

```
Animal() 
{
    this.name = makeRandomName();           
}
```

I don't get any errors, **regardless** of whether makeRandomName is static or non-static. Why?
What is the difference between 
`this.name = makeRandomName();` and `this(makeRandomName());`

I have never seen this syntax `this(method_name())` before, I have only ever seen `this.instance_variable = value`, so I am a bit confused. I am sure this has to do with super constructors and order of invoked methods, but it would be great to see an expert analysis of methods and constructors in this case and order of invoking methods. Many thanks in advance!

I was asked to post the entire code:

```
public class Animal {
    String name;
    Animal (String n)
    {
        this.name = n;
    }
    Animal() 
    {

        this(makeRandomName());
        //this.name=makeRandomName();

    }
    static String makeRandomName()
    {
        int x = (int) (Math.random()*5);
        String l[] = new String[] {"Zlatan", "Ibra", "Edinson", "Gigi", "T"};
        return l[x];

    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();
        Animal b = new Animal("M");
        System.out.println(a.name);
        System.out.println(b.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post all the source code.

Comment: makeRandomName is a method on the object, but the object hasn't been defined until you have called at least the super constructor.

Comment: Thank you DJClay, makeRandomName is a method on the object in which of the two cases? How are the two calls different more precisely? `this(makeRandomName());` and `this.name=makeRandomName();`

Answer (score 9):

For the first question - the reason `makeRandomName()` must be specified as static is because `makeRandomName()` is an instance method and will not be accessible until `super` has been called from within the constructor, which causes the class to be initialzed. What you are attempting to do is call `makeRandomName()` before the call to `super` initializes the class, thereby resulting in the compilation error.

For the second question - there is an implicit call to `super();` before your statment of `this.name = makeRandomName();`. `super(...);` must always be the first statement in the constructor, even if you don't write it explicitly. Therefore, the actual code of your second constructor is this:

```
Animal() {
    super();
    this.name = makeRandomName();
}
```

`makeRandomName()` is accessible at this point even if it is declared as non-static because the object has been constructed already.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case `this()` you are trying to call the class constructor and you are trying to pass it the results of a method defined in that class.  The object that you created in the first place hasn't been initialized at this point so it is trying to access a method from within itself that hasn't been initialized yet.  `super()` must be called before you can access the method but in this case you can't call `super()` and then `this()` because java requires `this()` to be the first statement in your constructor if you put it in there.

`this(makeRandomName())` is calling the constructor and trying to pass the result of `makeRandomName()` to the constructor call. The problem is that the object has not been initialized at this point so `makeRandomName()` cannot be called.

`this.name = makeRandomName()` is assigning the return of `makeRandomName()` to an instance variable of the class after the object has been initialized

It doesn't make sense to be calling the constructor inside the constructor because you will have a recursive situation happening...Unless there is some design reason for doing this but in that case you would need a base case to break out of the recursion at some point.

Comment: Thank you brso05! I do have a question: I keep hearing that in one case , the object has not been initialised yet so a non-static method cannot be called. In the other case, the object was initialised, so we can call either a non-static or a static method (it doesn't matter).
Why does `this(makeRandomName())` not initialize the object, whereas `this.name = makeRandomName()` initialises it? I'm still a little confused.

Comment: @Samy because if you invoke `this(makeRandomName())` it must be the first statement in the constructor meaning the implicit call to `super()` has not been made yet (so object is not initialized) where as if you do `this.name = makeRandomName()` then by default the `super()` is called before this line implicitly...

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this problem because you are calling an object (vs Class) method: "makeRandomName" before the superclass constructor has been run (you are passing in the results as a parameter). Before any method can be run on an object, the object's super constructor must have executed. That's why it's always the first line of a constructor

Comment: So I am calling an object method (`this(makeRandomName());` supposing makeRandomName is non-static) before super(). Thank you ControlAltDel. Question: Is super() not invoked implicitly as a first statement in a constructor even if we don't type it explciitly? That is what I thought. How come it works with the other variant? (` this.name = makeRandomName();`)

Comment: @Samy if you use `this()` then `this()` must be the first statement otherwise `super()` is the first statement.

Answer (score 1):

You called your `instance method` makeRandomName() before `super()` it is not accessible because no instance/object created yet.

The following constuctor works becasue the constructor itself called `super()` by default in the `first line` of the constructor body.

```
Animal() {
        //this(makeRandomName());
        this.name=makeRandomName();
}
```

Your following constructor you invoked `this()`, in this case `super()` will not be invoked in your constructor `Animal()` but in `Animal(String name)`, unfortunately `makeRandomName()` is not accessible.

```
Animal() {
   this(makeRandomName()); 
   //this.name=makeRandomName();
}


Animal(String name){
    // super() is invoked implicitly here...
}
```